# Do some people pronounce "women" same as "woman"?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, accent

This is something i've noticed lately. [Example 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VZpM0gVVi8), [example 2](https://youtu.be/bi7dZB2Dmuw?t=69) (1:10). (...i do not necessarily endorse these videos).
I can clearly hear them say "all woman"/ "why do pregnant woman".
I'm not a native speaker hovewer so i'm not 100% sure. Am i hearing it correctly? Is it a thing with some English accents?

Comment: Yes, some people pronounce 'women' as 'woman', as many words are pronounced differently by different people. But what is the real question here? Whether or not it has to do with accents?

Comment: I wanted to know whether it sounds the same to native speaker as well, and whether this is common enough that someone might have information about it, such as it being regional etc.

Comment: No, they don't sound the same to native speakers.

Comment: It's unlikely it's regional. I assume it's more common among non-native speakers. All the same, this sounds a little like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what do you want to find out ultimately, and why?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe. I guess all i wanted to know is "Is that a thing, or am i crazy". I apologize if this is not the place to ask this question.

Comment: **example 1** - the speaker seems to mean "womankind". **example 2 (1:10).** to me the speaker has the vestiges of a Spanish accent.